# Automatic Checkbox generating Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm trying to automate check box generation. If someone clicks and writes something in the C10 cell or lower like C11,C12... then right of the cell should appear a check box.

Its should look something like this:

[image: Checkbox]

How should I do  this?

**UPDATE!:**

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox

    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("C10:C1000")) Is Nothing) Then
        If Not (IsEmpty(Target.Cells.Value)) Then
            'If the cell is NOT empy, I should add a checkbox, to the right of the cell without text
            Set chkbox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Target.Left, Target.Top, Target.Width, Target.Height)
            With chkbox
                .Text = ""
            End With
        Else
            For Each chkbox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
                If Not Intersect(Target, chkbox.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                    chkbox.Delete
                End If
            Next chkbox
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you try so far ? any vba code ?. Thanks

Comment: My only problem is, that if I want to delete multiple cell, the checbox deletion not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox
    Dim cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C10:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("C10:C1000"))
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                'If the cell is NOT empy, I should add a checkbox, to the right of the cell without text
                Set chkbox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
                With chkbox
                    .Text = ""
                End With
            Else
                For Each chkbox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
                    If Not Intersect(cell, chkbox.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                        chkbox.Delete
                    End If
                Next chkbox
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```